# Error in running keras for deep learning in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, theano, keras

I had implemented a neural net architecture in keras using tensor flow as a backend.

Which is working fine in last month but when I tried to run the code again it gives a series of errors. I tried to uninstall my packages installed and reinstall it but it never worked for me. I also tried the same combination with theano as a backend but it still gives me error.

I am attaching the traceback of the hope I could get a better solution for my question.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeepNeuralNetwork.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib as contrib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import learn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.autoencoder import TensorFlowDNNAutoencoder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/autoencoder.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.base import TensorFlowBaseTransformer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.io import data_feeder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/dask_io.py", line 26, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .io import (from_array, from_pandas, from_bcolz,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .csv import read_csv, to_csv, read_table
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 147, in <module>
    CPU_COUNT = psutil.cpu_count()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cpu_count'
```

Comment: it looks like a problem in your `dask` installation. Do you get the same error with just `import dask.dataframe as dd`?

Comment: yes i do get the same error while importing dask.dataframe

Comment: what could be the solution for that

Comment: reinstalling `dask` for example. Do you get the same error if you create a new clean environment and just install `dask` via `pip` or whatever method you usually use?

Comment: k i will try it

Comment: i removed dask using pip uninstall then tried to reinstall using pip install dask but the same error exist

Comment: what did you recently change exactly? Are you installing the package directly from the github master branches? The error is strange because it seemingly stem from [this line](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py#L147), and is due to your `psutil` installation not having the attribute `cpu_count`. If you installed everything via `pip` can you show what version of `psutil` you have installed, with `pip show psutil`?

Comment: yeah you were right i was able to solve the issue the error was due to using a older version of psutil i just upgraded it and then another dependency arises named cloudpickle i installed it using pickle and now my code in tensor flow is running well thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the last lines of the backtrace:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 147, in <module>
    CPU_COUNT = psutil.cpu_count()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cpu_count'
```

the error is due to `dask` trying to call the attribute `cpu_count` of the module `psutil`.
This is probably due to some wrong version of `psutil` installed, and should be solved by simply upgrading or reinstalling it.